# Proxy-Authorization not sent over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, http-headers

I've made a man-in-the-middle proxy in Node.js. I implemented a `Proxy-Authenticate` and `Proxy-Authorization` flow that works perfectly for `HTTP` requests but the `Proxy-Authorization` is completely omitted for `HTTPS` requests. I am wondering if there is any logical reason for this.